# Without alert, my web service wont get called

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

This is my code where I am trying to call my RESTful web service in dotnetnuke HTML module. 
If i remove the alert in javascript and press submit button, the page doesnt redirect. And as I put the alert again, it works! I think it has something to do with the delay. I want to make this work without making use of the alert function. Please help.

```html
 <html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function s()
 {

 var a=document.getElementById('txt').value; 
var url= 'http://localhost:9737/RestServiceImpl.svc/xml/'+a; 
window.location = url;
   window.alert("hi");
  
} 
</script>
 </head>
 <body> <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="s();"/> 
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You have a flawed document structure - `script` tags go inside the `html tag` too (best make it a child of `head`).

Comment: @collapsar Thank u so much! I did that. But it still does'nt work!

Comment: That must be a problem of your setup - @Sandeeproop 's solution works perfectly fine (with a redirection to google in the code). Which browser do you use ?

Comment: @collapsar i am using firefox. If it was a setup or browser issue then it shouldnt be working at all even with the alert! but it works along with an alert! which seems very strange

Comment: press `ctrl-shift-j` in firefox, choose the `net` tab from the popup and see what network requests are logged when you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your `<script type="text/javascript">` just before ending `</body>` tag.

```
<html>
  <head><title></title> </head>
  <body> <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="s();"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     function s()
     {

       var a=document.getElementById('txt').value; 
       var url= 'http://localhost:9737/RestServiceImpl.svc/xml/'+a; 
       window.location = url;

     } 
    </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: i just tried what you said. It is still not working!

Comment: The explanation is not correct. The variable definition is encapsulated in a function and the assignment will only be evaluated when calling `s` which only happens after clicking the submit button (for obvious reasons, the relevant dom nodes are accessible at that time)

Comment: Any specific error??.not working means you are not getting data or URL is not changing?
I tried it locally it is working for me(changing the URL ).

Comment: @collapsar Can you please correct the code for me? I put the `<script>` inside the `<head>` tag!

Comment: @Sandeeproop when i click on submit button, it is supposed to redirect me to the specified url. But it doesnt happen when i remove the alert! It stays on the same page! I am working on dotnetnuke 7. Writing this code in the HTML module of the same! Thank you

Comment: @SwatiVerma: Could that be a caching problem? Are you sure that there is no reload/that the urls differ (try it with a redirection to someplace else, eg. google ) ?

Comment: @collapsar nope it still wont redirect! tried other urls

Comment: @SwatiVerma Which browser you are using?
Also please copy my answer code in HTML file and try to run it.
It think It will work,Don't use your localhost.Directly open that HTML into any browser and fill text box and submit it

Comment: @Sandeeproop i tried copying ur code. it doenst work

Comment: I'll what i have done. I have copied this code and saved this as test.html on my desktop. And now opened this html file in firefox browser.
At this time my url is "file:///C:/Users/43862388/Desktop/test.html" and after filling the textbox with some random value. my page got redirected to  "http://localhost:9737/RestServiceImpl.svc/xml/remdom%20value"

Comment: That's because the web service that I am calling is being hosted on my machine.

Comment: This means this code worked and page redirected to new location from initial location which is "file:///C:/Users/43862388/Desktop/test.html"

Answer (score 0):

need to prevent default, otherwise browser immediately navigates away

```
function s(event) {
 var a=document.getElementById('txt').value; 
  var url= 'http://localhost:9737/RestServiceImpl.svc/xml/'+a; 
  window.location = url;
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

alternatively you could `return false;` from function `s()`

Comment: tried that as well! I cant understand whats wrong! tried everything!

Comment: there is no error message as such! the page refreshes thats all, while it is supposed to redirect to the url specified.

Comment: @SwatiVerma add `return false;` like I suggested

Comment: yes i did that! added `return false;` it still wont work

Comment: can you confirm s() function is being called at all?

Comment: Yes it is being called @dark_ruby

Comment: can you explain what actually happens - does it just submit the form? while you expect it to redirect to given URL?

Comment: It simply stays on the same page. Kinda refreshes. Doesn't go to the URL

Comment: @SwatiVerma I created a jsbin http://jsbin.com/puxagikima/2/edit it works perfectly

Comment: is anyone using a dotnetnuke module? I think this is due to dnn tryin to connect to my web service. tryin to figure it out